# How to use PHP to search a string for words starting/ending with special regular expression characters?

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP to find out whether a string, which starts with a special regular expression character, occurs as a word in a text string.  This is the PHP code:

```
$subject = " hello [hello [helloagain ";
$pattern = preg_quote("[hello");
if (preg_match("/\b" . $pattern  . "\b/", $subject, $dummy)) { 
    echo "match";
} else {
    echo "no match";
}
```

The pattern starts with character [, hence, preg_quote() is used to escape it. There is an instance of *[hello* as a word in the subject so there should be one match, but the above preg_match() returns no match. I think the reason is that in the subject a special character is not recognized as the start or end of a word, but I can’t think of any way round this, any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that a word boundary will not match between a space and a `[` symbol.

Instead of using a word boundary you can explicitly search for spaces (and other separators such as commas and periods if you wish) before and after the word:

```
if (preg_match("/(\s|^)" . $pattern  . "(?=\s|$)/", $subject, $dummy)) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved that problem although I’d have preferred not to list all possible separators. I also need to count the number of occurrences of the pattern in the subject. I tried your solution on a slightly modified subject as follows:
    `$subject = " hello [hello [hello [helloagain ";`
    `$pattern = preg_quote("[hello");`
    `echo preg_match_all("/(\s|^)" . $pattern  . "(\s|$)/", $subject, $dummy);`
preg_match_all() returns 1 rather than 2 (now there are two instances of <i>[hello</i> in the subject separated by a single space), Why?

Comment: @user646234: Regex matches can't overlap. To solve this use a lookahead. I've updated the answer. Note for future reference: If you state your full requirements at the start you will get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you could just use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) with a leading space to separate words:

```
$subject = " hello [hello [helloagain ";
$pattern = " [hello";

if(strpos($subject, $pattern) !== FALSE)
  // ...
else
  // ...
```

I think that *not* using reg-ex here is actually a better method since you are looking for special reg-ex chars, and they do not have to be escaped if you use `strpos()`.

It would take some modification to be right in all cases, but this worked when I tried it.

Comment: Thanks. As stated in my comment to _Mark_Byers_ above, I also need to count the number of occurrences of the pattern as a word, hence, I had decided to use regular expressions.